# transition opacity ease out in css

Tags: css

my page transition as u can see here is the gif [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVbvg.gif) easing out gradually.
I want it to hide immediately after 2 sec without easing out.

the code :

```js
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let loader = document.querySelector('.vanilla-preloader');
        loader.style.opacity = 0;
        loader.addEventListener('transitionend', () => loader.remove());
     });
```

```css
.vanilla-preloader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
transition: 2.4s opacity;
pointer-events:none;
background: url('coco.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat #ffe1f2; /* Change the #fff here to your background color of choice for the preloader fullscreen section */
}
.elementor-editor-active .vanilla-preloader {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="vanilla-preloader" ></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the CSS transition animation / `transitionend` listeners and just using a basic `setTimeout`? That sounds like what you are asking for.

Comment: Just update the `transition` duration ? Try to change it from 2.4s to 0s for example.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than transition, use animation so you can keyframe the effect. See snippet below.

```css
.animation {
  animation: fade;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: inherit;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnqxx.jpg" height="200"/>
</div>
```